# How to install encrypted linux debian using hardware encryption on SSD

Tags: linux, debian, ssd, encryption, self-encrypting-drive

I got a partitioned SSD, 300gb for windows (unencrypted) and 200gb for linux debian that I would like to encrypt. Does anyone know how I can encrypt the linux system on the partition using the hardware encryption system from the SSD ? It's a 950 pro SSD.

Comment: To clarify do you mean  something like dm-crypt/luks  OR sed (Self encrypting devices) ?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 i'm not sure i'm novice i'll try to search those terms, but basically I want to have encrypted logs and data with minimal overhead, meaning I want to use the built in encryption feature in the ssd, I don't care about the rest. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your SSD has OPAL.
I have the 850 Evo.
You can use sedutil: https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil
The setup instructions are quite detailed. The worst disadvantage is that it breaks suspend. Otherwise, all good. You might also want to see https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/issues/6 if anything about the PBA does not work properly.

Comment: If you just want to make sure  folks aren't noisy   use  BIOS / Boot (aka power on)  and  HDD / SSD Passwords --- Saves you if these 'evil players'   decide to  migrate the drive elsewhere, like another machine OR  attempt  to boot it  via  say  usb and  mount your drive....  ( I do those and more on my  personal systems.)

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I'm a bit suspicious of ATA passwords. I'd recommend OPAL if your device supports it, but yes, I guess it is a risk, especially considering that this project has already switched maintainers.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 By the way a bit behind the time or what? :P

Comment: Protection in layers, most the  folks around me  are not smart enough to  break or  ask someone who can break an ATA pass but as I said  that is only  some of my  safeties.   OPAL assumes as well that like ata passwords that your trust the Manuf.  to not  backdoor it.

Comment: I guess that's a good point.  But then again, you never know.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSD & BIOS both support hardware encryption on the SSD itself (the OS won't even see it or have to do anything, no cpu overhead, I *think* suspended & hibernate would still work) then there *should* be an option in the BIOS somewhere to set a drive password - **NOT** just a boot or BIOS password. If nothing in the BIOS then something doesn't support it. Laptops seem more likely to support it.

It works similar to LUKS where erasing just the master key effectively "wipes" the drive.

Here's a little snippet & useful link from another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1008516/307834) of mine on SSD encrytion, definitely **[read the VxLabs linked page](http://vxlabs.com/2012/12/22/ssds-with-usable-built-in-hardware-based-full-disk-encryption/)**:

> [VxLabs' SSDs with usable built-in hardware-based full disk
>   encryption](http://vxlabs.com/2012/12/22/ssds-with-usable-built-in-hardware-based-full-disk-encryption/) page tells me:
>
> > Information on this is incredibly hard to find
> >
> > In some cases, the manufacterer uses the HDD password or ATA password (configurable via many laptop BIOSes, **very few desktop BIOSes**, or
> >     the [ATASX BIOS extension](http://vxlabs.com/2012/11/28/adding-the-ata-security-extension-bios-to-amibios/)) to encrypt the AES keys.

Comment: damn I didn't see any drive password in the bios how to know whether it got the function

Comment: Suspend and hibernate would depend from Bios to Bios I think. Mine supports it(or at least it has the option).